# Get website's status code in linux

Tags: linux, apache, http-status-codes

I have a small vps where I host a web app that I developed, and it's starting to receive a lot of visits.

I need to check/verify, some how, every X minutes to see if the web is up and running (check for status code, 200) or if is down (code 500), and if down, then restart run a script that I made to restart some services.

Any idea how to check that in linux? Curl, Lynx?

Comment: This is a better fit for serverfault, but take a look [here](http://www.pingdom.com/) -- they have a free plan.

Comment: thanks @josh3736 but I need to capture the result and according to the result do something or something else. I've posted an answer which works for me

Comment: Using a third-party monitoring service is a very good idea so you can be alerted if your server itself goes down. (I'm assuming your restart script is running on the VPS.)

Comment: yes, it is running on the VPS. I do agree that a third-party is useful, but it only alerts me... it doesn't solve the problem. Later, I think I will implement nagios

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I created two scripts:

1. site-statush.sh http://yoursite.com **=>** to check site status and if 200, do no thing, else invoke **services-action.sh restart**
2. services-action.sh restart **=>** to restart all services indicated in $services

Check it out at https://gist.github.com/2421072

Answer (score 2):

```
curl --head --max-time 10 -s -o /dev/null \
    -w "%{http_code} %{time_total} %{url_effective}\n" \
    http://localhost
```

Times out after 10 seconds, and reports Response Code and time

Curl will exit with an error code of 28 if the request times out (check $?)

Comment: yea, the `curl` was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on a sister website (serverfault)
https://serverfault.com/questions/124952/testing-a-website-from-linux-command-line

```
wget -p http://site.com
```

This seems to do the trick

Comment: this returns the page's content... not the status! Tnx any way

Answer (score 1):

For questions like that the `man` pages of the tools normally provide a pretty good list of all possible options.

For `curl` you can also find it [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

The option you seem to search is `-w` with the `http-code variable`.

**EDIT:**

Please see @Ken's answer of how to use `-w`.

Comment: yeap, `curl` is what I decided to use.